# Inserting a Video into a Div with HTML5/Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video

I am trying to insert a video and have it take up 100% of my body div on my homepage. Below my header, above my footer but 100% of that area! Basically its blue smoke and I want it to be the main focus when you get to the home page. I need it to be responsive, and I've heard that iphone and ipad will not recognize dimensions I give to the video?

I am trying this out currently with a demo version.
http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-video-35477950-blue-ink-explosion.php?st=86374c9

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNvjL/10/

```
<div id="body">

<video width="1000" height="350" autoplay loop preload="auto">
  <source src="media/smokehome.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="media/smokehome.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="media/smokehome.webm" type="video/webm">
  <object data="media/smokehome.mp4" width="1000" height="350">
    <embed src="media/smokehome.swf" width="1000" height="350">
  </object> 
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:0px solid #FFF;"> 
</canvas> 

</div>
```

i read to use a canvas because Iphone and ipad will recognize for size?

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tushar2289/KCqGx/)

Check out my fiddle to get your video in between your header and footer. Also, it always best practice to maintain your aspect ratio so that your video doesn't start looking all funny.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <div class="video_holder">
        <video controls>
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your          browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
    <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
video {
    height: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.video_holder {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
header, footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0096ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTML/CSS and it will work for iphone/ipad, check out the fiddle on how to do it:

```
#video_background { 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%; 
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -1000; 
overflow: hidden;
}
#video_pattern { 
background-image: url(../images/pattern.png); 
position: fixed; 
opacity: 0.8; 
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
z-index: 1
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MxUQQ/

Note: You might want to consider whether a video background is a good idea for mobile, depending on internet speeds this might be a bad user experience